# Getting realtime and full output using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to get the realtime output as well as the full output. I have the below code that outputs the realtime output of the command very well but I also need to capture the full output which can then be sent in an email without interrupting the realtime output

```
backup = subprocess.Popen("rsync ....", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in iter(backup.stdout.readline, b''):
   print(">>> " + line.rstrip())
```

I have tried adding the following but it causes the realtime output not to display

```
output = backup.stdout.read()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you collect the complete/full output along the way?

```
backup = subprocess.Popen("rsync ....", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
full = []
for line in iter(backup.stdout.readline, b''):
   line = line.rstrip().decode('utf8')
   print(">>>", line)
   full.append(line)

output = '\n'.join(full)
print("full output:", output)
```